# Text gets mixed after converting pdf to word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I converted a PDF file written in Farsi but when i open the word file the text is mixed and the words aren't in the right order.

I used the adobe PDF reader to convert the PDF file.

Comment: Welcome to the world of non-perfect software.

Comment: Which software have you exactly been using for converting the PDF document? How has the document been created? Do you get better results when you make the document accessible beforehand?